# SQL Server - Using Quoted Identifier ON and OFF and Getdate()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with my script *SQL*, please help me.

Ex:

I have a insert statments:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (Code, Date) VALUES (1, GETDATE());
```

When I execute this insert, retuns the follow message:

> "Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Server
>   HENRIQUE-PC, Line 5 INSERT failed
>   because the following SET options have
>   incorrect settings: **'QUOTED
>   _IDENTIFIER'**. Verify that SET options are correct for use with
>   indexed views and /or indexes on
>   computed columns and/or filtered
>   indexes and/or query notificatio ns
>   and/or XML data type methods and/or
>   spatial index operations.".

Now, when I used `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`, my insert is executed with success.

Ex:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (Code, Date) VALUES (1, GETDATE());

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
```

> (1 row(s) affected)

What relationship betwhen `GETDATE()` and `QUOTED IDENTIFIER`?

Why I need to use *QUOTED IDENTIFIER* in this case?

I believe it is because of getdate. Why?

Thanks.

Henrique Melicio

Comment: Is 'CUSTOMER' a table or a view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Henrique,

The reason you're getting that error is not related to `GETDATE()`, it has to do with indexes on columns from your `CUSTOMER` table. This bit from SQL Server 2008's `SET Statements (Transact-SQL)` document explains the issue in more detail:

> When you are creating and manipulating
>   indexes on computed columns or indexed
>   views, the SET options ARITHABORT,
>   CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL,
>   QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS,
>   ANSI_PADDING, and ANSI_WARNINGS must
>   be set to ON. The option
>   NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT must be set to OFF.
>
> If any one of these options is not set
>   to the required values, INSERT,
>   UPDATE, DELETE, DBCC CHECKDB and DBCC
>   CHECKTABLE actions on indexed views or
>   tables with indexes on computed
>   columns will fail. SQL Server will
>   raise an error listing all the options
>   that are incorrectly set. Also, SQL
>   Server will process SELECT statements
>   on these tables or indexed views as if
>   the indexes on computed columns or on
>   the views do not exist.

Comment: Thanks AJ01, my script is OK now.